# session variable authorization in hasura action call

Tags: next.js, auth0, serverless, hasura, next-auth

### **Is it possible to create a custom attribute for session_variables?**

Whenever I call a function without a server through the actions created in Hasura, I need to send in the request header an `x-hasura-admin-secret` to authorize the call to my endpoint, the problem with this is that this call will have a role admin o which is not correct when executing this call when the function is called from a user.

Ex.:

```
const execute = async (variables) => {
  const fetchResponse = await fetch(
    "https://myapp-hml.herokuapp.com/v1/graphql",
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 
            // I would like to pass the user authorization here
            'x-hasura-admin-secret': process.env.HASURA_ADMIN_SECRET },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        query: HASURA_OPERATION,
        variables
      })
    }
  );
  const data = await fetchResponse.json();
  console.log('DEBUG: ', data);
  return data;
};
```

That way I receive requests with an administrator type authorization, and I would like to receive this authenticated request with an authorization from the user who called the action that triggered this function without a server, because that way I get through a log to know which user triggered the action who called this function without a server.

---

> **What would really meet my need is:**

I need to send a custom attribute in my `session_variables` object
when my **Serverless Function**  receives the POST call through
**Hasura Action**.

Ex.:

```
{
    session_variables: {
        'x-hasura-role': 'user',
        'x-hasura-user-id': 'facebook|3813878855387420',
        'x-hasura-authorization': 'Bearer xxxxx' // custom attribute

    },
    input: { title: 'Title' },
    action: { name: 'insertTodo' }
}
```

In Hasura's actions I can define which user rule can call this action that triggers this function without a server, but I would like to reinforce this by sending in the method `execute` the value received from `session_variables`.

**I'm using serverless functions at Vercel with Next.js authenticating with NextAuth.js with JWT type authentication using Auth0.**

Comment: Do you have access to the user's JWT from Auth0 inside your serverless function when you're getting ready to send the POST to Hasura? You may be able to just replace `x-hasura-admin-secret` header with the `Authorization` header and send the JWT instead

Comment: I receive an object with session_variables as described above, however it does not come with the user's authorization, and I would like to make this value come ...

Comment: If you have the admin-secret, user id and user role you don't need any other information. You can just send them as headers with the request to Hasura and it will automatically use them in the correct way to evaluate the user permissions